# Bijection Contruction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My knowledge of constructing bijections is very poor and I would really appreciate any clarification or assistance. 
The question I am having trouble with is the following:

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set.  Let $F=\{\{0,1\} \xrightarrow{f} S \}$ be the set of functions from $\{0,1\}$ to $S$.  Construct a bijection $F \xrightarrow{\alpha} S \times S$.

Comment: what is your "bijection" definition??

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Does the "obvious" choice $\alpha(f)=(f(0),f(1))$ work?